# Understanding Gray-Level Hit-or-Miss-Transform Definition

Tags: definition, pattern-recognition

From a paper I am using for my Bachelor thesis:

> The HMT transform by the pair $(A,B)$ associates to a binary image $X$ the set $X\otimes(A,B)$ of positions where the translate  of $A$ fits inside $X$ and at the same time the translate of $B$ fits inside the complement $X^C$ of $X$.

And regarding the gray-level extension of the HMT in particular:

> We use a definition of HMT operator that assigns to $A$ and $B$ gray-levels $a$ and $b$, respectively. Following this definition, the gray-level (GL) HMT compares the minimum intensity $a_{min}$ in $A$ to the maximum intensity $b_{max}$ in $B$: $$S_s^t = I_s\otimes(A,B)(p)=\begin{cases}(I_s \ominus A)(p)-a & if\ (I_s \ominus A)(p) \geq (I_s \oplus B)(p)+a-b\neq\infty\\-\infty & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ If $a_{min}>(b_{max}+a-b)$, then the point is selected by the GL HMT.

I have difficulties understanding this definition. There is no more information given.

It is obvious from context, that $S_s^T$ is subset of $\mathbb Z^3$. This is also supported by the point of the first paragraph quoted above, saying that $X\otimes(A,B)$ is a set of positions. From this point my first question arises:

(1) What sense does it make that the left part of the equation above is a subset of $\mathbb Z^3$ whereas the right part of this equation is scalar-valued? The equation formally implies $S_s^t=-\infty$ in certain cases.

I believe that this is the core problem to understanding the definition, and the second obscurity will vanish by answering the first question:

(2) Yet it is unclear, what exactly $a$ and $b$ are: where are their values supposed to come from? And what might $p$ stand for?

Comment: I think we both, try to understand the same paper ;-) I have the same problem to understand the Point(2), what exactly a and b are. My idea is that are the values in A and B from the SE ancor (the center of the SE). What do you mean?

Comment: I'm really not sure whether this is right. But I believe that $a$ is the foreground intensity and $b$ is the background intensity - not from the image, but as additional parameters of the SE. Therefore, $a-b$ is the minimum intensity difference of foreground and background, that muse be given at some point, in order for this point to belong to $S_s^t$.

Comment: I think your assumption is correct, my idea make no sense, after a sharp thinking about it. :D But the problem is to apply the Formula $$ a_{min}>(b_{max}+a−b)
$$
to the example in Figure 2. You have the grey-leves Black(0) < dark Grey(1) < light Grey(2) < White(3)
and the SE is (002222200). The scale is not correct. From the SE covered imagearea is 00122100 SE 0022<b>2</b>2200 //The bold number is the anchor <br> Im 001222100 And now I have the question what exactly is $$
a_{min},b_{max},a,b
$$